# Client-Server: How is a request performed on the client considered "safe"?

Tags: authentication, validation, networking, web-applications, client-server

So, I was reading about implementing a Client-Server architecture, but I've noticed something I cannot wrap my head around.

I'll put a game example:

Let's say the client has to take an item from a chest, this chest has 2 items in it: **A** and **B**.

This Chest has an ID, equal to **1** and the content of this chest (and the chest itself) is saved on the server database.

The client user clicks on the chest, which in his game also has ID 1, it runs a function:

function FetchFromChest(int chestID)

Which asks the server what's in the chest with id chestID (the chest the player clicked), gets the data (A and B) and displays it on the screen.

Now without going forward, from my understanding, that is an example of client-server setup and communication, but I cannot help but see a major flaw in it which makes it worthless for me.

The function "FetchFromChest" runs on the client, and it could be changed to fetch a specific chest with a specific ID (or any chests really), which will make the request still valid, but will display the wrong chest.

Now I've learnt that the client cannot be trusted, so I don't get how it works together. I need to legitimately say "The player is trying to fetch from chest: chestID", but to get what the player is looking into, isn't that a request that the client (and the client only) can do? And therefore, can be hijacked in some way since the client cannot be trusted?

Answer (score -1):

You should manage security in the backend layer. Let's say you are trying to fetch chessId 2, but you are not a player in that game, then the server should respond with an 403 Forbidden response because the current logged user is not part of that game. Every chess game should have a list of participants and only if the requesting user (a session, jwt, etc) is part of that list then you should be able to manipulate that game entity.